# How to trigger a conditional email when a new Google Sheet row is added via Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am collecting requests via Google Forms and they are stored in a Google Sheets. So whenever a new submission comes, I would like to send an email based on the choices.

Currently I have created a separate tab where country and recipient of the email exist.

[image]

In my form response tab, I wrote a formula:

```
=query(ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(B2:B;Sayfa2!$A$2:$B$4; 2; false))); "where Col1 <>''")
```

It looks like:

[image]

So pulling the data when a new submission comes. However, my GAS does not trigger email

```
//setup function

var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

if (ActiveSheet.getName() == 'Form Yanıtları 1') {

 var StartRow = 2;

 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;

 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,4);

 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
 
   
 var message = ""

  //iterate loop

 for (i in AllValues) {

   //set current row

   var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
   var row = AllValues[i]
   var alertRecipient = row[3];
   var emailMessage= row[2];
   var emailSubject = "A suggestion received for your style guide"

     //set HTML template for information

     message +=


         "<p><b>Option: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +

           "<p><b>Comment: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +

             "<p><b>Recipient: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
                      "</p><br><br>";


   }

 }//For loop close

 //define who to send emails to

 // var SendTo = "myemail@email.com";

 //set subject line

 // var Subject = "New Form";

 //send the actual email   if message is not empty

 if (message) {

   MailApp.sendEmail(alertRecipient,emailSubject,emailMessage);

 }//if message

}//if sheetName Review
//End Func
```

I set up my GAS trigger as onEdit.

Could you please help me to understand where I do the mistake?

Thanks so much in advabce!

Comment: Use a 'onFormSubmit' trigger. [See here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#:~:text=An%20installable%20form%20submit%20trigger%20runs%20when%20a%20user%20responds%20to%20a%20form.%20There%20are%20two%20versions%20of%20the%20form%2Dsubmit%20trigger%2C%20one%20for%20Google%20Forms%20itself%20and%20one%20for%20Sheets%20if%20the%20form%20submits%20to%20a%20spreadsheet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your contributions. I found an easier solution and wanted to share:

```
    function sendEmailv3() { 
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses Sheet'); 
     var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),4).getValue();
     var message = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),3).getValue();


     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "SubjectLine", message,{noReply:true});
  }
```

I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, launch once myTriggerSetup

```
const adresseEmail = 'xxxxxxxxxxx@orange.fr'
const sujet = 'New form ...'

function myTriggerSetup() {
  if(!isTrigger('onFormSubmit')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
  }
}
function isTrigger(funcName) {
     var r=false;
     if(funcName) {
       var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
       var allHandlers=[];
       for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++) {
         allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction());
       }
       if(allHandlers.indexOf(funcName)>-1) {
         r=true;
       }
     }
     return r;
}

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var responses = e.namedValues;
  getData(eval(responses))
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: adresseEmail,
    subject: sujet,
    htmlBody: '<table>' + result + '</table>', 
  });
  var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var column = e.values.length + 1;
  sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue('Envoyé : ' + d);
}

let result = ''
function getData(obj) {
  for (let p in obj) {
    if (obj[p]!=null){
      if (typeof obj[p] != 'object' && typeof obj[p] != 'function'){
        result += '<tr><td>'+ obj[p] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (typeof obj[p] == 'object') {
        if (obj[p].length){
          result += '<tr><td><b>'+ p + ' :</b></td></tr>';
        }
        getData(obj[p]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: lunch vs launch?

Comment: ok, sorry, I'am french !! execute via the script interface to put the onformsubmit trigger in place

Answer (score 1):

Posting this for documentation purposes, solution was provided in a comment by [JPV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70213466/how-to-trigger-a-conditional-email-when-a-new-google-sheet-row-is-added-via-goog/70242851#comment124118982_70213466).

#### Issues:

- An [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger fires when **users manually** change values in the spreadsheet. A form submission causing a new row to be added to a sheet doesn't fire this trigger.
- A simple `onEdit` trigger won't be able to do actions like sending an email, since that requires authorization, an simple triggers cannot access services that require authorization (see [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)).

#### Solution:

- Install an `onFormSubmit` trigger instead, which will fire whenever the form is submitted. This could be installed [for your form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) or [for the spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onformsubmit) to which submission data is getting sent. You can either install it [manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) or [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically).
- Instead of using `SpreadsheetApp` methods to get the form response data, use the [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), which also contains submission data ([these](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) are the object fields if you install the spreadsheet trigger, and [these](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) are the ones if you install it in your form).